# Using probability to minimizing conditional evaluations for speed-up

Tags: javascript, algorithm, performance, probability

Consider a scenario when you have integers in range [1, BIG_NUMBER]; 
If the number is divisible by 3, print `foo`;
If the number is divisible by 5, print `bar`;
Divisible by both 3 and 5, print `foobar`;

One way to do it is

```
// READABILITY IS GOOD
const func1 = length => {
    for (let i = 0; i <= length; i++) {
        let output = i;
        if (i % 3 === 0) output = 'foo';
        if (i % 5 === 0) output = 'bar';
        if (i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0) output = 'foobar';
        console.log(output);
    }
};
```

Now if we think along the lines of probability,
probability to be divisible by 3:
p(3) = 1/3,

similarly divisible by 5:
p(5) = 1/5

and divisible by both
p(3 && 5) = 1/15

divisible by either one of the two 
p(3 || 5)  = p(3) + p(5) - p(3 && 5)

Now instead of the above snipped, I write nested if statements:

```
const func3 = length => {
    for (let i = 0; i <= length; i++) {
        if (i % 3 === 0) {
            if (i % 5 === 0) {
                console.log('foobar');
            } else {
                console.log('foo');
            }
        } else if (i % 5 === 0) {
            console.log('bar');
        } else {
            console.log(i);
        }
    }
};
```

**Approach is to put most probable if statement first, and least probable if statement last, which should minimize conditional evaluations.**

Will it attain speed up? Still checking at my end, and **will post my findings also**. But I am just wondering does anyone think along these lines. Is it even used in practice ? or just a waste of time, that also screws up a readable code for a minimal gain

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), another site in the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: What kind of a speed-up are you targeting? It's not useful to try to optimize a code running in a fraction of the microsec to get a nanosec speed-up.

Comment: The second version should be more efficient not because it tests the more probable condition first, but because it only computes and compares each remainder once. The first version does each modulo and comparison twice. Either way, both conditions *do* have to be tested, so the order you test them in shouldn't matter.

Comment: For what it's worth, I don't think this question belongs on Code Review, because Code Review is for general, open-ended feedback on code - your question is specifically focused on whether a particular refactoring is an efficiency improvement and can be justified by probability theory. I think it would be suitable for Stack Overflow if you showed some attempt at measuring the efficiency yourself rather than just asking us to tell you if it's more efficient.

Comment: @kaya, thank you. Ok, shall post my findings instead. I did not write the most probable case first. But instead, I was checking if such a thought process exists,  or is worthwhile to compromise readability. Target is large CFD simulations, running for several days on a cluster.

Comment: I made a small perf test, the average execution time of million rounds was 11/10 msecs (without the console.logs). Most likely the bottleneck here will be the output printing/saving. If the code runs for days, you're probably not going to output the results to the console. You might want to test different techniques to save the results.

Comment: @Teemu, thank you.  console.log was hypothetical, and a bad example as it involves I/O. The actual code performs CPU operations.  Just give me some time. I will post my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do either of these arrangements: you do have to test for both conditions in some form or another.  Instead, use a progressive build of the output:

```
noise == ""
if (i % 3 === 0) noise += "foo"
if (i % 5 === 0) noise += "bar"
if (noise == "") noise = i
console.log(noise)
```

Simple, readable, and reasonably quick.